# What does the second "rule" of linked data mean?

Tags: linked-data

I am reading the four principles for linked data.

the second one is

> Use HTTP URIs so that people can look up those names.

I couldn't understand it. I tried to read some on internet but still didn't understand it.

I understood that the second rule is to give description to the **names** that has uri, and which was identified in the first rule

is that correct please?

Answer (score 3):

The first rule says to use URIs as "names for things". There are many [URI schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes) available, for example `http`/`https`, `urn`, `data`, `tag`, `mailto`, `xmpp`, `ftp`, etc.

The second rule says

- to use the `http` URI scheme (¹), and
- to provide some information when accessing this URI (²).

A HTTP URI acts as identifier/name *and* locator/address, i.e., it’s a URL. If you’d use a tag URI like `tag:example.org,2014-01-01:foobar` or a mailto URI like `mailto:alice@example.org`, no one could look it up (e.g., by entering it in a browser’s address bar) and learn something about it, as it’s just an identifier, not a locator.

So in other words, the second rule makes sure that the data is part of the Web.

(¹) `https`, while not explicitly mentioned, is probably fine, too
(²) and the third rule says to provide this information *also* using standards like RDF and SPARQL